# How to calculate view-space vertex coord from screen-space vertex coord given FOV and screen resolution?

Tags: directx, coordinate-transformation

I am writing a hook for a very old game that used DX 6.1 and doesn't have L&T.

I am intercepting calls to DX with `float x, y, z, rhw` vertex position and I want to reconstruct x y z in view-space coordinates. I know FOV and screen resolution, but I have problem with finding formula for back transform. Could someone give me such formula, or point me to relevant Internet sources?

And one more thing - Sometimes I am receiving very strange coordinates, for example I've manage to capture in the debugger:

```
float x = 105.96786.0f;
float y = 1963.8353.0f;
float z = -2343.6121.0f;
float rhw = 0.0f;
```

How should I handle such cases in reverting formula?

Comment: So you want to calculate screen coords from world coords? Then you will go with `screenCoord = Transform(worldCoord, View * Proj)` You will have to scale it to the viewport. If you want the other direction, use the inverse matrix.

Comment: I want the other direction. When I pass x/y/z/rhw to inversed matrix I'll get original worldCoord?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that x/y is scaled to the viewport (in the range of [-1,1]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nico Schertler pointed out in comment above that I should use inverted matrix - this works